# how to get a variable from ajax query

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I want to get a UserID from ajax query and i want to save it as a variable for search user...I got the UserId successful and i don't have a idea how to store it's value as a variable..I using Spring framework

```
    var data = {}
    data["id"] = $(this).attr('data-button');
    anNo=  $(this).attr('data-button');


    $.ajax({
                                type : "post",
                                contentType : "application/json",
                                url : "restservice/impapp/?id=" + anNo,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success : function(data) {
                                var jString = JSON.stringify(data);
                                var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
                                deleteRow('dataTbls')
                                        for (var x = 0; x < jdata.impitems.length; x++){
                                var tr = "<tr>";
                                var td1 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].hsCode + "</td>";
                                var td2 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].productName + "</td>";
                                var td3 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].serialNumber + "</td>";
                                var td4 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].modelNumber + "</td>";
                                var td5 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].authorizationNumber + "</td>";
                                var td6 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].authorizationDate + "</td>";
                                var td7 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].yearofManufacture + "</td>";
                                var td8 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].useFor + "</td>";
                                var td9 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].physicalForm + "</td>";
                                var td10 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].type + "</td>";
                                var td11 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].description + "</td>";
                                var td12 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].uom + "</td>";
                                var td13 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].qty + "</td>";
                                var td14 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].uoc + "</td>";
                                var td15 = "<td>" + jdata.impitems[x].value + "</td></tr>";
                                $("#dataTbls").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5 + td6 + td7 + td8 + td9 + td10 + td11 + td12 + td13 + td14 + td15);
                                              }



$('#appcategory').val(jdata.appcategory);
                                                $('#userName').val(jdata.userId);

                                            },

                                                error : function(e) {
                                        alert('Error Occurred!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
                                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                                            }
                                            });
```

My ajax query is working fine...userID return succesfully to the userName textFeild...I want to store it as a variable for call the user

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('CHA')">
                                        <td><a href="<c:url value='/view-user-' />" class="btn btn-success pull-right">EXPORTER</a></td>
```

I want to store userID like this ...

```
<c:url value='/view-user-'{userID}/>"
```

Please help me

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ go through this

Comment: I also created all conrollers and mapped succesfully,,,I have a problem in my jsp

Comment: if you would have seen here in this ex http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/ model attritube has been set model.addAttribute("userForm", user); and accessed in jsp <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="${userActionUrl}"> accordingly

Comment: Ok sir thank u...Im now watching your site